conda: The file specified the interpreter '../python3.12', which is not an executable command
I cannot run pip. I have it installed in a conda / mamba environment.
$ which pip                                                                                                                 (llm-movie-recommender) 26.01h
/home/torstein/miniforge3/envs/llm-movie-recommender/bin/pip
$ which python                                                                                                                    (llm-movie-recommender) 
/home/torstein/miniforge3/envs/llm-movie-recommender/bin/python
$ conda env list                                                                                                                  (llm-movie-recommender) 
# conda environments:
#
                         /home/torstein/anaconda3
                         /home/torstein/anaconda3/envs/py310
base                     /home/torstein/miniforge3
llm-movie-recommender  *  /home/torstein/miniforge3/envs/llm-movie-recommender
py312                    /home/torstein/miniforge3/envs/py312

$ pip install themoviedb                                                                                                     (llm-movie-recommender) 621ms
exec: Failed to execute process '/home/torstein/miniforge3/envs/llm-movie-recommender/bin/pip': The file specified the interpreter '/home/torstein/mambaforge/envs/llm-movie-recommender/bin/python3.12', which is not an executable command.

Note the paths. I had previously installed mambaforge, but removed it and installed  miniforge. They are equivalent distributions of conda, just with different paths.
I can do python -m pip install themoviedb and it works, but I would rather fix the paths.

Try conda install pip --force-reinstall
